# Remove unwanted html contents from webpage using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to remove unwanted html meta tags and contents from my webpage body as these tags causing issues in mobile view. and theses contents are coming from external server. want to remove all the contents between div and table tag

```
<div class="my_body">
```

my html contents

```
<table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)** selector and select element excepts the `table` and remove them using **[`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)**

```js
$('div.ymail_body>:not(table)').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row ymail_body">

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title></title>
  <!--[if gte mso 9]> <style data-immutable> table td { border-collapse: collapse; } 
</style> 
<![endif]-->
  <style data-immutable="">
    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
      .mobile-hide {
        display: none!important
      }
      .mobile-wide {
        float: none!important;
        width: 100%!important
      }
      .mobile-block {
        display: block!important;
        width: 100%!important
      }
      .reply {
        padding: 5px 0 0 15px!important
      }
    }
  </style>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

---

Or you can use **[`prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/)** to select all previous element

```js
$('div.ymail_body table').prevAll().remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row ymail_body">

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title></title>
  <!--[if gte mso 9]> <style data-immutable> table td { border-collapse: collapse; } 
</style> 
<![endif]-->
  <style data-immutable="">
    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
      .mobile-hide {
        display: none!important
      }
      .mobile-wide {
        float: none!important;
        width: 100%!important
      }
      .mobile-block {
        display: block!important;
        width: 100%!important
      }
      .reply {
        padding: 5px 0 0 15px!important
      }
    }
  </style>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

---

Using pure JavaScript you can use **[`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)**

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('div.ymail_body>:not(table)'), function(ele) {
  ele.parentElement.removeChild(ele);
  // ele.remove();
  // remove() doesn't work for IE 7 and below
});
```

```html
<div class="row ymail_body">

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title></title>
  <!--[if gte mso 9]> <style data-immutable> table td { border-collapse: collapse; } 
</style> 
<![endif]-->
  <style data-immutable="">
    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
      .mobile-hide {
        display: none!important
      }
      .mobile-wide {
        float: none!important;
        width: 100%!important
      }
      .mobile-block {
        display: block!important;
        width: 100%!important
      }
      .reply {
        padding: 5px 0 0 15px!important
      }
    }
  </style>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you pranav for your answer but how to do the same thing in pure javascript and not jquery

Comment: @chetan You can use `querySelectorAll()` then iterate and remove them

Comment: @chetan : glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
jQuery(".ymail_body").remove();
```

Comment: I think the issue with this is that the table is in the diff?